# Alfresco datalist send email on very new item creation

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I have applied rule on datalist folder like on each item creation, it should drop an email to respective person.

Below is the script for the same:

```
function main()
{
    var site = siteService.getSite("hardik-test");
    var dataListsContainer = site.getContainer("datalists");
    var dataLists = dataListsContainer.getChildren();

    var fullName, manager,joiningDate;

    for(var x=0;x<dataLists.length;x++)
    {
         var dataList = dataLists[x]; 
          var props = dataList.getProperties(); 
         var title = props["cm:title"]; 

        if(title.equals("Employee")) 
        {
            var dataListItems = dataList.getChildren(); 

            for (var y = 0; y < dataListItems.length; y++) 
            {
                var dataListItem = dataListItems[dataListItems.length-1];
                var dataListItemProps = dataListItem.getProperties(); 
                fullName = dataListItemProps["emp:fullName"];
                manager = dataListItemProps["emp:manager"];
                joiningDate = dataListItemProps["emp:joiningDate"];
            }   
        }
    }
    // create mail action
    var mail = actions.create("mail");
    mail.parameters.to = "xyz@xyz.com"; //manager email id should be there
    mail.parameters.subject = "Task assigned to you.";
    mail.parameters.from = "xyz@xyz.com";
    //mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath("Data Dictionary/Email Templates/Notify Email Templates/notify_user_email.html.ftl");
    mail.parameters.text = "Hi "+manager +"," + "\n A new employee " +fullName +" will be joining our team on "+ joiningDate + "." +
     "\n For details, Please click here. \n  Regards, \n Administrator" ;
    mail.execute(document); 
}
```

script is running every time when we create new item but in the email it's not fetching the latest data we entered.

If we want to use email template, then how can we pass parameter(custom values) to email template?

Want to create link that will redirect to datalist.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many times when the Alfresco source can be instructive. If you take a look at the MailActionExecuter class you'll see that it has several parameters defined:

```
public static final String NAME = "mail";
public static final String PARAM_LOCALE = "locale";
public static final String PARAM_TO = "to";
public static final String PARAM_CC = "cc";
public static final String PARAM_BCC = "bcc";
public static final String PARAM_TO_MANY = "to_many";
public static final String PARAM_SUBJECT = "subject";
public static final String PARAM_SUBJECT_PARAMS = "subjectParams";
public static final String PARAM_TEXT = "text";
public static final String PARAM_HTML = "html";
public static final String PARAM_FROM = "from";
public static final String PARAM_FROM_PERSONAL_NAME = "fromPersonalName";
public static final String PARAM_TEMPLATE = "template";
public static final String PARAM_TEMPLATE_MODEL = "template_model";
public static final String PARAM_IGNORE_SEND_FAILURE = "ignore_send_failure";
public static final String PARAM_SEND_AFTER_COMMIT = "send_after_commit";
```

One of those is PARAM_TEMPLATE_MODEL which you would set by using "template_model". The "model" in that parameter is what should be catching your eye. It means you can pass in a set of keys and values by using that parameter.

Later, in the source for that class we see where the parameter is read and then used to build the full model that is then passed in to the Freemarker template:

```
Map<String, Object> suppliedModel = null;
if(ruleAction.getParameterValue(PARAM_TEMPLATE_MODEL) != null)
{
    Object m = ruleAction.getParameterValue(PARAM_TEMPLATE_MODEL);
    if(m instanceof Map)
    {
        suppliedModel = (Map<String, Object>)m;
    }
    else
    {
        logger.warn("Skipping unsupported email template model parameters of type " + m.getClass().getName() + " : " + m.toString());
    }
}

// build the email template model
Map<String, Object> model = createEmailTemplateModel(actionedUponNodeRef, suppliedModel, fromPerson, toRecipients);
```

So, if you comment in the reference to the template and you pass in an additional parameter to the action, assuming your template makes use of the items you add to the model, you should see those in the resulting email.

Your code would look something like:

```
var templateModel = {};
templateModel["fullName"] = fullName;
templateModel["manager"] = manager;
templateModel["joiningDate"] = joiningDate;
mail.parameters.template_model = templateModel;
```